# Why does setting my CALayer's opacity seem to also affect sublayer's opacities?

Tags: ios, core-animation, core-graphics

I am not explicitly setting my sublayers' opacity -- only the superlayer's via the `opacity` property. While the superlayer's opacity does change as expected, my sublayers' opacities also appear to change, causing elements below those sublayers *within the superlayer* to be exposed. Why might this be happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why is this surprising you? What did you expect to happen? If you don't want this, don't put those sublayers inside that superlayer. Just put them on top of it (perhaps in a separate superlayer).

---

EDIT: I understand your issue now. You're running into a Core Animation optimization. Core Animation is trying to save time by just applying the opacity to all the sublayers prior to compositing. That way it can composite just one time (which lets it ignore the container superlayer). Most of the time this works out and improves performance.

What you want it to do is all the compositing within the superlayer, then apply the opacity, and then re-composite the result with everything else. This is called rasterizing; which basically means "please turn me into a bitmap before you composite me with anything else." You can request this by setting `shouldRasterize` on your superlayer.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear. When I decrease the opacity of a given CALayer, my intended effect is for that layer and its sublayers to render exactly the same as before, only with a lower alpha. What is actually happening is that the superlayer's alpha is decreasing (which is what I want), but /within/ the superlayer sublayers' alphas are also decreasing (which is what I don't want.) Why should changing the opacity of a superlayer affect the alpha channels of its sublayers?

Comment: In other words, why does a superlayer's alpha determine how its sublayers should mask each other /within that superlayer/? Shouldn't the sublayers be completely oblivious to their parent's alpha channel?

Comment: Interesting -- I'm curious how that actually ends up optimizing performance. It seems to me that setting sublayers' opacities would increase the complexity of the compositing and thus have the opposite effect on performance. Either way, you're right, I was planning on using shouldRasterize anyway. Didn't realize it would be necessary to simply get correct alpha blending behavior.

Comment: This is interesting but it does not work with CATransformLayer.  Unfortunately, it seems that (for now) there's basically no way to have a true 3D shape become partially transparent without exposing what lies on the other side of the shape (strange behavior, as the OP stated) - unless I'm missing a solution for that case, too.